# Proxy Authentication Required, Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Getting this error when make api call in retrofit

> Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=407, message=Proxy Authentication
>   Required, url=http://example.com/test.xml}

below was my api call.

```
 private void showProxies() {
   serviceCall = apiService.listOfServers();
    serviceCall.enqueue(new Callback<ServerListModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerListModel> call, Response<ServerListModel> response) {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                ArrayList<Proxies> proxyArrayList = response.body().proxiesArrayList;
                 showProxyDialog(proxyArrayList);
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(BrowserActivity.this, "Server 407 error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ServerListModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what's your base url you set up?

Answer (score 1):

you have add proxy to you Retrofit object

```
java.net.Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,  new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort));
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().proxy(proxy).build();

Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().client(client);
Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
```

Comment: java.net.Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,
                new InetSocketAddress("http://sl.myproxyvpn.com/", 80));

Comment: you have to put this code in a `Thread` to run on `Background`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was connected to the proxy network this issue is not related to retrofit.